# libxl library use in c++

Tags: c++11, libxl

When I create a project visual studio 2015 I can work this libxl library hovewer I could not be able to work that library on visual studio qt gui application project.

I try everything whatever I know.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "QtGuiApplication5.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qpushbutton.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "libxl.h"
using namespacenclude <Qt libxl;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Book* book = xlCreateBook();

    if (book)
    {
        if (book->load(L"..\\Lab_Bus Datebase.xlsx"))
        {
            Sheet* sheet = book->getSheet(0);
            if (sheet)
            {
                const wchar_t* s = sheet->readStr(2, 1);
                if (s) std::wcout << s << std::endl << std::endl;
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            std::cout << "At first run generate !" << std::endl;
        }
        book->release();
    }
    std::cout << "\nPress any key to exit...";
    _getch();
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QtGuiApplication5 w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Link2019 error: Severity Code Description   Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_xlCreateBookW referenced in function main  QtGuiApplication5

link1120 error: Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  QtGuiApplication5   C

Comment: an unresolved external symbol means there no definition found for used function.
Maybe you are missing some lib to link. use `#pragma comment(lib, "libname.lib")`

Comment: I took same errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure visual studio project properties to use required lib. Refer [this](http://www.libxl.com/vscpp.html) link for the same.
You are using `.xlsx` file so instead of `xlCreateBook` use `xlCreateXMLBook`. Apart from this you need to use `using namespace libxl;`as well

Below are [Factory functions](http://www.libxl.com/documentation.html):

- `Book* xlCreateBook()`
  Create a binary book instance for xls format. This function should be called first for receiving a book pointer. This function and other classes are in libxl namespace.
- `Book* xlCreateXMLBook()`
  Create a xml book instance for xlsx format. This function should be called first for receiving a book pointer. This function and other classes are in libxl namespace.

See below image above code works fine at my machine.
[image]

Comment: I did whatever need which write on reference page, It is not reletaed with xlsx, even if I delete whole code without first line I received same error like that                                  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 Book* book = xlCreateXMLBook();                            return a.exec();
}

Comment: Are you sure you are using expected lib on your platform?
eg. try to use x86 lib with x86 visual studio build environment

Comment: well, I am trying same example on my system, let's see what will happen

Comment: everything works fine at my end, I am getting data from sheet

Comment: Probably you have misconfigured the project properties I guess.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helping, my problem related with win32.